# Recommend 2nd logic and discrete math books?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

I passed all the required undergraduate math for the computer science program at my university. It didn't include a course in complex analysis and the advanced required courses were about discrete math and numerical methods (for PDE e.g. Runge-Kutta methods and similar).

The undergraduate books I enjoyed the most were "Discrete Mathematics" by Norman Biggs and especially Graeme Forbes' "Symbolic Logic". Those are not very similar books but I enjoyed them both (and I also enjoy analysis but not diff equations). 
My background is a course in discrete math (where the Norman Biggs book was used) and a course in logic where Graeme Forbes Symbolic Logic was used. I want to learn more like that but I don't know exactly what I'm looking for. I also took all other undergraduate math courses and passed them (analysis and numerical methods) but my interests were discrete mathematics and symbolic logic with exactly those books. If I enjoyed those 2 books, can you recommend me more reading? I'm currently reading Peter Cameron's combinatorics book and David Wunsch's complex analysis to teach myself some more. But Peter Cameron's book is not very similar to Norman Bigg's book.

I want to "dig deeper" in mathematical logic and discrete mathematics (group theory, fields and rings) - should I read galois theory, more abstract algebra, Church's thesis, Emil Post and study Haskell's, Curry's and Frege's results and try and follow famous logicians and algebra if my interests are more towards discrete math, logic and combinatorics and algorithms rather than analysis and mathematical physics?

I am familiar with Gödel's and Turing's results and everything in the two books mentioned by Biggs and Forbes.

Comment: Maybe a reasonable thing to do would be having a look at older questions tagged [book-recommendation+discrete-mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+discrete-mathematics) or [book-recommendation+logic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+logic) to see whether you will find some books you like there.